# How to update a database record using hibernate with no primary key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create a web service using Jersey and connect to the database using Hibernate.

Due to security reasons, I don't want to pass the primary key value from the server to the client or the opposite direction. In that case, how can I update a record? From examples I've seen you should call `session.load(key)` and change the returned object, but like I said, I won't be having the key value.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "security reasons"? Not sure if you're not making everything worse.

Comment: Someone might intercept the message and take advantage of it

Comment: Like... how? Is your primary key a password? And how else would you identify a record?

Comment: Let's say for now a user can only change his own details (his db record details). Isn't the key saved in the current session or something like that?

Comment: If you store it in the session, it will be stored in the session. If you don't, it won't. But really, passing the primary key shouldn't be a problem. You should just make sure the user has the right to update/delete/get the requested data.

Comment: OK so this part is missing for me.. I have yet to make any user logging mechanism so I don't have a way of identifying it yet. How can you manage users and their session using Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

You may not pass a primary key to update a record but it implies two things :

- You must have another way to identify in a unique way a record (maybe a business key or a composite key).
- it may cost in performance since your PK is automatically indexed, not the other fields. Creating multiple indexes may be a cost.